# How Can I get rid of this horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: horizontal-scrolling

My site is **http://www.dermatek.com/**

All of a sudden there is a horizontal scroll bar on firefox, I don't see it on IE or Chrome though.

Can someone tell me how I can fix this? I was editing some sizes but not sure how it could have happened.

Thank you

Here is a link to a screenshot of what i looks like on my Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X5Sy.jpg

Comment: Just a tip: it's <br />, not </br>.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that for some reason...  I have to edit it.

Comment: I don't see a horizontal scroll bar in Firefox 20.0.1

Comment: See my answer, it will help you to quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it has something to do with your javascript:

Firebug shows:

```
<ul id="nav" style="width: 1037px;">
```

When I disable JS all seems fine.

Comment: Where did you disable the JS at?

Comment: You can do that in your browser. But thats just for testing purpose and no solution.

Comment: When I took the width off, the horizontal bar dissapeared. I am using shopify, I need to figure out where it is probably?

Answer (score 0):

Inspected the element on your site.

Seems that you footer has some fixed width element.

```
.footer-linklists {
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
<div style="float: left; width: 473px;">
```

It is not good practice to use inline css. And fixed width might cause the overflow.

You can try to use percentage instead of the fixed width. Also take the padding width into consideration.

Also try to use overflow: hidden might solve the issue. But it might cause some part of content being hidden.

Hope this can give you some threads to solve the problem.

Comment: I changed the widths to percentages but it didn't really change it. 
Where would I try to put the overflow hidden?

Thank you